# Yii ajax jquery multiple request just fist one works

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

Many input field and button pairs for ajax request works only for first time. After first request-response other buttons doesn't call ajax function.

There's a data grid list. Each row has a Title field (as input) with a button to call ajax function for updating this field and refresh list.

first time I click on one of the buttons everything works fine, data sends and list refresh with new data. but after this when I click on one of the buttons nothing happens , even function doesn't call.
Where I'm doing mistake?
My ajax function:

```
$('.titleBtn').click(function(event){

    var id = $(this).attr('name');
    var title = $('#' + id).attr('value');


    var formAction = '".$this->createUrl('article/changeTitle')."';

    $.get(formAction,{id:id,title:title},function(result){
        $.fn.yiiGridView.update('article-grid');


        }
    );
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

My grid list:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->route),
'method'=>'get',
'id'=>'Artform',
)); ?>

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id'=>'article-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'ID',
        array(
            'header'=>Yii::t('labels','Title'),
            'name'=>'Title',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=> function($data) use ($model) {
                    return '<input type="text"   id="'.$data->ID.'" value="'.$data->Title.'"><button type="button"  name="'.$data->ID.'" class="titleBtn" >Update</button>';
                                },

        ),
    ....
),
)); ?>
//Some buttons irrelevant to this subject for submitting whole list.
<?php $this->endWidget('CActiveForm'); ?>
```

Comment: When did you run the $('.titleBtn').click function? is it in a ready() function? or outside?

Comment: It's in ready() function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the event using [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$('#Artform').delegate('.titleBtn', 'click', function() {
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `afterAjaxUpdate` option to your TbGridView and add js code to invoke after ajax update and set your handlers.